# How to use eicontinue parameter on wikipedia api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to understand how the `eicontinue` parameter works, the documentation says:

```
eicontinue: Used to continue a previous request and eicontinue
```

When more results are available, use this to continue.

And that's it. Basically wikipedia has a limit of 500 calls, or 5000 for bots. I want to use the parameter in order to make new calls once one is finished. For that I am checking the `last id` of the last article the loop finds:

```
newQuery();
function newQuery() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(spacetime)), null, 4));
  jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eicontinue=2|"+myId+"&eilimit=500&noimages=true&mobileformat=true&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?", {
    disablelimitreport: true,
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
    $.each(data.query.embeddedin, function(i, item) {
      counter++;
      curTitle = item.title;
      if (i===data.query.embeddedin.length-1) {
        myId = item.pageid;
        myTitle = item.title;
      }
      wikiText();
    });
  });
}
```

[The documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Embeddedin) is very poor, from what I could find around on the web I should do:

```
eicontinue=2|"+myId+"
```

Which is fine, but what i don't understand is: What is it the 2 parameter? `eicontinue=2|"`

If I remove that I get:

```
Cannot read property 'embeddedin' of undefined
```

I went on the [embeddedin parameter page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Embeddedin) to read more but it didn't help much.

On the documentation page, there is [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Stub&eilimit=5) and the result is:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "eicontinue": "2|4571809",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "embeddedin": [
            {
                "pageid": 2428176,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Congelation"
            },
            {
                "pageid": 2581310,
                "ns": 2,
                "title": "User:Rpyle731/sandbox/archive1"
            },
            {
                "pageid": 2621895,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Battledore and shuttlecock"
            },
            {
                "pageid": 2710517,
                "ns": 1,
                "title": "Talk:Scott Fahlman"
            },
            {
                "pageid": 3954860,
                "ns": 3,
                "title": "User talk:PBS/Archive 6"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And from there I can see:

```
"continue": {
        "eicontinue": "2|4571809",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
```

Which is even more confusing and it looks like it is using both `eicontinue` and `continue-||` while not listed in the documentation, I don't get it. And then again, the number `2|`

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of Javascript is very limited, and I haven't even begin to work out details of using the MediaWiki API with it. However, it might be  useful to you to know what little I have found out about it so that I can use Python.

Since that documentation page you mention says that `Embeddedin` can be used as a generator you have two choices: so-called 'raw query continuation' or generator continuation.

**A simple first call to `Embeddedin` under the first option ('raw continuation') would be:**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox&eilimit=5
```

Examining the results of this call I can see that the value of `eicontinue` is `"0|324"`. Then the second call, for the next batch of results would be,

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox&eilimit=5&eicontinue=0|324
```

IOW, just stick the `eicontinue` value from the previous result as a parameter on the end each time.

But then, MediaWiki advises against raw continuations.

**Better option: `Embeddedin` as a generator.**

In developing this answer I'm reminded that MediaWiki is not as inscrutable as its documentation might suggest. If you can approximate a correct request the engine will point out mistakes that can help you make corrections.

Here's a first call for embedded templates.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&geititle=Template:Infobox&format=jsonfm&prop=info&generator=embeddedin&=inprop=url&geilimit=5
```

The first time I tried it with `gpllimit=5` and the engine complained that it did not recognise this parameter. Sooner or later I will remember that generator parameters are (or seem to be) the same as corresponding raw parameters prefixed with a 'g'.

Examining the output, easy because I used the `jsonfm` format, I see I must stick `&geicontinue=0|324` on the end of the original url to get the next batch of results.

And, yes, the documentation is mind bending.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really helpful, a few questions in regards:

1. `What is 0?` - 2. why did you use `inprop=url`? 3. What is the difference between `generator` and `raw`?

Comment: 1. I don't know definitely. It seems to be a sequencing number that MediaWiki returns. At this point I would expect that if you send off `&geicontinue=0|324` you will get back '1|xxx'. But I don't know. 2. That's a hold over from code I've been using in Python. I think it gives you more info. Ref my remark about experimentation. :) 3. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Raw_query_continue says something cryptic about this at the top of the page. Read that you will know everything I know.

Comment: it's absolutely cryptic indeed, now on that page it mentions `accontinue`, I used `eicontinue` and you suggested `geicontinue` and I don't understand the differences, all I know is that we should avoid, then again, `rawcontinue`

Comment: If you use it enough you will become as insane as the authors. Promise.

Comment: i'm already there, trust me, but not just the whole api is crazy, to make the parsing too, all the html is all over the place

Comment: like.. i want to use `prop=text` and it won't work https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&geititle=Template:Infobox&format=jsonfm&prop=text&generator=embeddedin&geilimit=5

Comment: You want the texts of the pages where the templates are embedded?

Comment: what I am saying is that if I use `prop=text` using `generator` won't work, while if I do it using `list` it works and I don't know why. Then again, I don't know what `generator` means and what is the difference with `list`

Comment: At this point I don't know. If I learn something within a reasonable time I will come back and post it here.

Comment: it's just all over the places,

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like

```
var query = {
    action: 'query',
    // etc
};
var promise = jQuery.getJSON(url, query);
function processBatch(data) {
    process(data); // process next batch of data
    if (!data.continue) {
        return jQuery.Deferred().resolve();
    }
    jQuery.extend(query, data.continue); // add/replace continue parameters
    return jQuery.getJSON(url, query).then(processBatch); // recurse
});
promise.then(processBatch);
```

Comment: thanks, but tbh it works what I used and we have in the question, what I don't know tho is what that parameter means

Comment: Continuation parameters are opaque and should not be manually interacted with. It's just something you need to roundtrip to preserve internal state so that the API can continue listing the results where it left off.